# angularjs search filter issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

Below is my plnkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/f6LYS2aGrTXGkZ3vrIDD?p=preview

I have issue on Search Page

```
angular.module('plexusSelect', []).directive('plexusSelect', ['$ionicModal',
    function($ionicModal) {
        // Runs during compile
        return {
            scope: {
                'items': '=',
                'text': '@',
                'textIcon': '@',
                'headerText': '@',
                'textField': '@',
                'textField2': '@',
                'valueField': '@',
                'callback': '&'
            },
            require: 'ngModel',
            restrict: 'E',
            templateUrl: 'templates/plexusSelect.html',
            link: function($scope, iElm, iAttrs, ngModel) {
                if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model
                $scope.allowEmpty = iAttrs.allowEmpty === 'false' ? false : true;
                $scope.defaultText = $scope.text || '';
                $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('plexusSelectItems.html', {
                    'scope': $scope
                }).then(function(modal) {
                    $scope.modal = modal;
                    $scope.modal['backdropClickToClose'] = false;
                });
                $scope.showItems = function($event) {
                    $event.preventDefault();
                    $scope.modal.show();
                };
                $scope.hideItems = function() {
                    $scope.modal.hide();
                };
                /* Destroy modal */
                $scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                    $scope.modal.remove();
                });
                $scope.viewModel = {};
                $scope.clearSearch = function() {
                    $scope.viewModel.search = '';
                };
                /* Get field name and evaluate */
                $scope.getItemName = function(field, item) {
                    return $scope.$eval(field, item);
                };
                $scope.validateSingle = function(item) {
                    $scope.text = $scope.$eval($scope.textField, item) + ($scope.textField2 !== undefined ? " (" + $scope.$eval($scope.textField2, item) + ")" : "");
                    $scope.value = $scope.$eval($scope.valueField, item);
                    $scope.hideItems();
                    if (typeof $scope.callback == 'function') {
                        $scope.callback($scope.value);
                    }
                    ngModel.$setViewValue($scope.value);
                };              
                $scope.$watch('text', function(value) {
                    if ($scope.defaultText === value) $scope.placeholder = 'placeholderGray';
                    else $scope.placeholder = 'placeholderBlack';
                });
            }
        };
    }
])
```

Where in I have reference **http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.14/js/ionic.bundle.js** ionic bundle than my second directive search filter will stop working but at the same time, if I reference **http://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0-beta.1/js/ionic.bundle.js** it works search filter in both directive.

In beta.14 angularjs 1.3 is used and in beta.1 angularjs 1.2

So somebody told me that it can be the migration issue, But I check angularjs migration documentation but I could not find anything. Kindly somebody help me what can be the issue.

Comment: If you see plunker there is two directive, in second directive when you open and try to type in search box it will not filter same as first directive but if you referene 1.0.0-beta.1. It will start working

Comment: I will explain you again. there are two directive. second directive will get items from rest api by value of first directive. until there everything is proper. But Now when you open second directive and type in search box (i.e filter) it will not filter as expected. Kindly check below links so you will understand http://postimg.org/image/ahok50e29/

http://postimg.org/image/svz38zqcx/

Comment: @tasseKATT  sorry by mistake I delete your comment

Comment: Don't worry, I was the one deleting it as I found what was not working. I will post the problem and solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem:

This is due to the [following](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-3) breaking change in Angular 1.3.6.

Excerpt:

> filterFilter: due to a75537d4,
>
> Named properties in the expression object will only match against
>   properties on the same level. Previously, named string properties
>   would match against properties on the same level or deeper.
>
> ...
>
> In order to match deeper nested properties, you have to either match
>   the depth level of the property or use the special $ key (which still
>   matches properties on the same level or deeper)

In the first use of your directive `items` have the following structure:

```
[
 { property: 'Value' }
]
```

And in your second use:

```
[
 { Destination: { property: 'Value' } }
]
```

Sadly a bug fix that you probably need wasn't introduced until [1.3.8](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#138-prophetic-narwhal-2014-12-19):

> filterFilter:
>
> make $ match properties on deeper levels as well
>   (bd28c74c, #10401)
>
> let expression object {$: '...'} also match
>   primitive items (fb2c5858, #10428)

### Solution:

Use Ionic with AngularJS **1.3.8** or later.

Change your HTML to the following:

```
<label ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { $: viewModel.search }" ...
```

Initialize `viewModel.search` as an empty string:

```
$scope.viewModel = { search: '' };
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/ZAM33j82gT4Y6hqJLqAl?p=preview

Comment: you are dude. I salute you. newbie like me cannot learn without guys like you

Comment: I found some issue again. If you see now I cannot filter just word "Kuwait" but anything else I can filter why is it so ??

Comment: My bad, didn't notice. There is a property called `__metadata` that contains an url (and a bunch of other things) that contains `kuwait`, so all objects fill match that. I will give you a solution soon.

Comment: I will wait for it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Is it enough to filter on the names? The name that you are showing.

Comment: I don't got your point. You mean filter only city name and not city code correct ?

Comment: Yes exactly. Is city name enough?

Comment: Yea for while it is okay until we find solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69474/discussion-between-tassekatt-and-milind).

Comment: Probably best with a custom filter like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/Yz4bdtIe8EzIWuKZwmKw?p=preview